# How to find all table references from Oracle 10G PL/SQL functions and procedures?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, complexity-theory

How to find all table references from Oracle 10G PL/SQL functions and procedures?

I definitely can execute the following SQL statement:

```
select * from dba_source where text like '%tbl_c%'
```

but I wonder how to find all functions that call functions that refer to table used.  For example I can have a function A that calls function B that uses table tbl_c.  If I'll execute aforementioned SQL I'll find funciton B but then I have to execute another SQL to find A.  As you know the cyclomatic complexity could be 3,4,5 levels deep or even greater.

Greatly appreciate in advance for your explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**dba_dependencies** is where to start.  Example:

```
 SELECT      owner
             || '.'
             || NAME
             || ' ('
             || DECODE (TYPE,
                        'MATERIALIZED VIEW', 'MV',
                        'DIMENSION', 'DIM',
                        'EVALUATION CONTXT', 'EVALCTXT',
                        'PACKAGE BODY', 'PKGBDY',
                        'CUBE.DIMENSION', 'CUBE.DIM',
                        TYPE
                       )
             || ')' objdep,
                referenced_name
             || ' ('
             || DECODE (referenced_type,
                        'EVALUATION CONTXT', 'EVALCTXT',
                        'NON-EXISTENT CONTXT', 'NO-EXIST',
                        'PACKAGE BODY', 'PKGBDY',
                        'CUBE.DIMENSION', 'CUBE.DIM',
                        referenced_type
                       )
             || ')' refr
        FROM dba_dependencies
       WHERE owner = :usn
    ORDER BY objdep;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer to use [ALL_DEPENDENCIES](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1041.htm#sthref935) when looking for object references rather than ALL_SOURCE. Adding to a hierarchical query, you could get what ever you need.